# Gurobi AssertionError when adding variable

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have a Gurobi model in Python that causes an error when declaring the variable as shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

num_p = 2
num_s = 2
num_d = 2

penalty_matrix = np.array([[1 / num_s * abs(0 - t) for t in range(num_d)] for _ in range(num_p)])

model = gp.Model('error-example')

# Create variables
error_variable = model.addVars(range(num_s), range(num_p), range(num_d), obj=penalty_matrix, vtype=GRB.BINARY)

model.optimize()
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 14
     11 model = gp.Model('error-example')
     13 # Create variables
---> 14 error_variable = model.addVars(range(num_s), range(num_p), range(num_d), obj=penalty_matrix, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
     16 model.optimize()

File src\gurobipy\model.pxi:2950, in gurobipy.Model.addVars()

AssertionError:
```

When I change num_s to 1, the error disappears but I really dont get the core of the problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Objective coefficients can be put as a scalar, dictionary or a list. If scalar value is provided then all variables get the same objective coefficient. If a dictionary is given then value for each variable will be pulled from the dict, using the indices argument to build the keys. If given list, then variables will get the corresponding objective coefficients from the list. In case of list or dictionary the length should match with the length of the indices (from which the variables are indexed).

Please look at the below listing. I am not sure how you derived the `penalty`. So if you will see the number of variables = 8, and then the length of objective coefficients is also kept at 8.

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB

num_p = 2
num_s = 2
num_d = 2

# old
# penalty_matrix = np.array([[1 / num_s * abs(0 - t) for t in range(num_d)] for _ in range(num_p)])

# logic of building the matrix need to verified
# list : corresponding to each index a penalty value is generated
penalty_matrix = [1 / num_s * abs(0 - t) for s in range(num_s) for t in range(num_d) for _ in range(num_p)]
# above resolves to [0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]

model = gp.Model('error-example')

# Create variables
error_variable = model.addVars(range(num_s), range(num_p), range(num_d), obj=penalty_matrix, vtype=GRB.BINARY)

model.optimize()
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for any language errors as English is not my first language, and some parts were machine-translated.
This may be because you have provided a numpy array as the obj argument instead of a scalar value, a dictionary, or a list.
When the obj argument is a scalar value, each variable created will use it as the target coefficient. Conversely, if the obj parameter is an array, it must match the length of the index parameter. In such a case, each variable will use the value at the corresponding position in the array as the target coefficient. Thus, when you set num_s to 1, your penalty matrix array will have only one row, with the same length as range(num_s), and therefore there will be no error. However, if num_s is set to 2, the penalty matrix array will have two rows, while range(num_s) only has one element, resulting in an assertion error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).